# Deny access to Central Administration

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, user, access

How to deny access to Central Administration in SharePoint 2010 for sample user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added the `All auth user` group into the SharePoint Central admin then it will give the access to all users.

You can go Central admin > Site Actions > Site Permissions. You will see 2 groups over here

- Delegated Administrators with Contribute Permission
- Farm Administrators with Full control.

Make Sure Only authorized user added here. By default farm admin / Install account is added here by setup.